# Pulsed DC From 'pure' DC (Via Switching System Without Moving Parts)

Tags: circuit-design, dc, high-frequency, diy, history

I want to create a circuit or mechanism that will let me switch the output from the starting value to 0 and back. **My input is pure DC.** I want to do this with fairly basic DIY supplies if possible (no modern electronics, old-school stuff). I'm looking for an output of around 50-60 MHz but I'd be satisfied with something far, far lower, if this isn't possible. **I also want something that involves no moving parts.**

I don't need an indepth description, just a link to a description of something along these lines.

Some people on here have had issues understanding what pulsed DC is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsed_DC
In short, pulsed DC is a type of DC current, current that does not change direction, whose value fluctuates, in my case from the starting value to 0 and back.

Thank you all.

Comment: "Pulsed DC (PDC) or pulsating direct current is a periodic current which changes in value but never changes direction." -- Wiki.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question on this same subject? Why do you say some people on here have issues understanding very basic things like pulsing a DC voltage?

Comment: @Andyaka They voted it closed. One guy got really upset as he somehow thought that switching on and off would make AC.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't know how he would have come to think this, as he's a computer hardware engineer, but nonetheless. I think the issue may be one of terminology, i.e., periodic current vs. alternating; but nonetheless. LOL.

Comment: Without definitions of "modern", "old school", and "far, far lower" this question is not answerable. Why is it important that you have no moving parts?

Comment: By old school I mean stuff analogous to what would have been around in the 1800s, and as for moving parts, just because that's my goal. Oh and as far as low, it could be really low like 100 Hz

Comment: @Herb I'm one of the moderators here. I'm old :-). My and our aim is to help and not to annoy. This is a very useful site but you have to attempt to fit in so we can all benefit.  1. If a question is closed then improving it as suggested and then requesting reopening is preferred to deleting and reposting it. Deletion wastes the effort that people have put into comments or answers - even if you don't appreciate some of them. 2. I'm a professional engineer and have been 'playing this game' for over 50 years.  ...

Comment: ... I assure you that if you turn DC on and off with a square wave  - or any other -  be it by mechanical switch, discharge lamp ... or  any other ... THEN the resultant waveform IS a mixture of AC & DC. eg if you had 12V DC turned on an off at 2 Hz you would have a 6VDC level + a +/- 6V AC square wave = a summation of sine waves. Your seeing this as "switched DC" is entirely understandable and is a reasonable picture for simple purposes. For real world analysis it's AC with a DC offset. 3. I edited your comment about the user who tried to convey the above fact to you. ...

Comment: ... Words such as you used are in everyday use, but better not used if you wish to maintain polite discussion. 4. It helps greatly if people can understand your overall application/purpose/picture. Giving as much detail as possible helps us help you. eg research for story telling is fine (although world building may also be useful).. You mentioned a Homopolar generator (a nicely ancient DC electrical energy source) and various frequency of on/offing - some at rates unlikely to be achievable - others easily doable. Again, a good overall picture helps us heaps.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you for the comment. I agree with you mathematically. I know that if you 'break it down' you're working with a summation of waves. But I was not talking about the AC component, I was referring the whole thing, which as you know, isn't usually thought of as AC, certainly not the sin waves people typically think of as AC.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm very thankful for you knowledge, BTW. (Also sorry for causing issues here.) The person who was mad at me seemed to be in a really bad mood for some reason. He said I should study for like 2 years to find out about how the result of switching is AC, when it should have been clear what I meant.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon To explain why I think it does not make sense to call switched power of this kind AC, think of electroplating, say, copper: This switching is compatible with the process; copper atoms will move from anode to cathode. On the other hand, if the combined values actually do reverse direction, then plating won't take place.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Almost all DC generators produce a mix of waves at a number of frequencies, obviously you know all this. And the result is usually purified to make a flat-line signal. However, both what I think of as 'wild' or 'untamed' DC (the mix) and the refined form do not reverse direction as a whole.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Once again I know you're aware of all this, so, my question is really what should I call the out put? "Something that looks like rectified AC."? It seems to me that a lot of people use the idea of pulsed DC as a simple way of describing the subject. To me personally, that guy's statements seemed like saying, "That's not a wire", "You need to study Physics," "It's actually a collection of subatomic particles." It just seemed like a strange thing out of nowhere.

Comment: In any case, I really am thankful for your time and will keep your comments in mind in the future. I'll also try and improve this thread if needed, although I think the gas lamp idea seems good other than the frequency being lower than I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try gas discharge lamp oscillator. Connect a lamp in parallel with a capacitor and feed it from DC through a resistor.  When the capacitor charges to the ignition level of the lamp the arc in the lamp discharges the capacitor and the arc vanishes. The capacitor start again to get charge.

These oscillators were common before the era of transistors. Read this for details: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson–Anson_effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%E2%80%93Anson_effect)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to produce a rectifier output from a 50-60MHz sinusoid, without integrated circuit packages or microcontrollers. You can start with a sinusoidal oscillating circuit; for something in your desired frequency range, look up the Colpitts oscillator, originally implemented with vacuum tubes. It is possible to build this with transistors or op amps, but be prepared to pay for a fast switching device (for 50 - 60MHz operation). When you have the sinusoidal signal, rectify it with a high speed diode, and you will have your desired output.

Comment: The idea is good and correct. But, I'm looking for straight-up switching with no AC and no rectification. Nevertheless, thank you for the input. I think the gas discharge lamp oscillator idea above is a good option, I just hope I can configure it to get the low to go near 0. Thank you!

Comment: The downside to the gas discharge lamp oscillator concept, is that I can't see it going anywhere near 50-60 MHz.